# Jquery pulsate changing color or image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have a div change colors using the jquery pulsate code but i want it to change from red to black, but i heard to do this you have to download a certain plug in. so instead i want it to pulsate to a picture. so far i have these two codes:

```
 <img id="book" src="36.gif" alt="" width="105" height="105"
      style="position: absolute; top: 585px;
    left:585px;" />

and

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#white36").click(function () {
    $('#book').animate({
      $(this).effect("pulsate", { times:3000 }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you got it wrong, you are not supposed to use the .animate() method.

also for .pulsate() to work you need to include jquery UI in your html file.

I haven't tested it but it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#white36').click(function () {
          $('#book').effect("pulsate", { times:3000 }, 500);
    });
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Pulsate